# Views Link Issue

Tags: 7, views

I am having an issue with a views photo gallery. I am using something similar to this http://www.lullabot.com/articles/photo-galleries-views-attach the only difference is I am using Drupal 7.

My question is how could I make the image that shows on the galleries page link to the gallery itself and not the single image?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 1):

The secret is on rewriting the link back to the gallery on the image node so that instead of the regular text it will show the image.

In your view fields:

1. Add the image and set the format to thumbnail and hide it from the display.
2. Add the entity that links back to the gallery and make sure to check "Link label to the referenced entity".
3. Go to the rewrite results section and in the "Rewrite the output of this field" add the replacement pattern that correspond to your image and click "Apply".
4. Limit the view results to 1 and hide the pagination.